# Formula to calculate flat-lined revenue over 12 months after a 1 month delay

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm having trouble devising a formula enabling me to calculate the revenue based on delaying the revenue by 1 month and then flat-lining the revenue over 12 months.

This is my worksheet:

[image: Worksheet Screenshot]

The base data for 2018 orders are in cells `F6:Q9`.

The base data for 2019 orders are in cells `S6:AD9`.

Currently there is an order for Mar 2018 (cell `H6`) and the revenue profile should show a 1 month delay so there would be no revenue for April but from May 2018, the March order of £20,000 should start to reflect £1,667 (up until Apr 2019).

The formula would also need to take into account both the orders from `F6:Q9` (2018 orders) and from `S6:AD9` (2019 orders).

In cell `I1`, I have entered `1` (to reflect the one month delay).

In cell `I2`, I have entered `12` (to reflect the number of months the revenue needs to be flat-lined by).

The revenue profile starts at cell `AE6` and this is where I'm having trouble ascertaining what formula to use.

I tried to use an offset formula but I couldn't get it to work. I don't know how to approach the solution.

Comment: can you share your sheet?

Comment: Please upload the Sheet & the Formula you have used with !!

Answer (score 0):

The formula required is a *slightly* complicated array formula.

Here is your spreadsheet with the formula showing the expected results:

[image: Screenshot of worksheet]

This formula needs to be array-entered in `AE6` and then filled/copy-pasted down and to the right as far as required):

```dart
{=SUM(IFERROR(INDEX(6:6,N(IF(1,COLUMN()-(COLUMN($AE:$AE)-COLUMN($F:$F))-COLUMN(INDEX(6:6,1):INDEX(6:6,$I$2))-$I$1))+(COLUMN()-(COLUMN($AE:$AE)-COLUMN($F:$F))-COLUMN(INDEX(6:6,1):INDEX(6:6,$I$2))-$I$1>=COLUMN($R:$R)))/$I$2,0))}
```

---

**Explanation:**

The prettified version of the formula is as follows:

```dart
{=
SUM(
  IFERROR(
    INDEX(
      (6:6),
      N(IF(1,COLUMN()-(COLUMN($AE:$AE)-COLUMN($F:$F))-COLUMN(INDEX(6:6,1):INDEX(6:6,$I$2))-$I$1))
      +(COLUMN()-(COLUMN($AE:$AE)-COLUMN($F:$F))-COLUMN(INDEX(6:6,1):INDEX(6:6,$I$2))-$I$1>=COLUMN($R:$R))
    )/$I$2,
    0
  )
)}
```

The formula is a lot easier to understand if you consider that for a 12 month duration and a 1 month delay, the second argument of the first `INDEX()` is roughly equivalent to:

```dart
COLUMN()-(COLUMN($AE:$AE)-COLUMN($F:$F))-{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12}-1
```

The formula basically works by generating an array of offsets to access the orders of the previous `I2` number of months, delayed by `I1` months, relative to the current cell.

Stepping through the formula in `AK6` should make the above clearer:

- `COLUMN(INDEX(6:6,1):INDEX(6:6,$I$2))`
  → `{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12}`
- `COLUMN()-(COLUMN($AE:$AE)-COLUMN($F:$F))-{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12}-$I$1`
  → `{37}-({31}-{6})-{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12}-1`
  → `{10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0,-1}`
- `N(IF(1,{10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0,-1}))`
  → `N({10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0,-1})`
  → `{10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0,-1}`
- `{10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0,-1}+({10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0,-1}>=COLUMN($R:$R))`
  → `{10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0,-1}+({10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0,-1}>={18})`
  → `{10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0,-1}+{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}`
  → `{10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0,-1}`
- `INDEX((6:6),{10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0,-1})/$I$2`
  → `INDEX(6:6,{10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0,-1})/12` → `{24000,0,20000,0,0,"Opportunity Name1","bWmd1","Col C val","Col B val","Col A val","Col A val",#VALUE!}/12`
  → `{2000,0,1666.67,0,0,#VALUE!,#VALUE!,#VALUE!,#VALUE!,#VALUE!,#VALUE!,#VALUE!}`
- `SUM(IFERROR({2000,0,1666.67,0,0,#VALUE!,#VALUE!,#VALUE!,#VALUE!,#VALUE!,#VALUE!,#VALUE!},0))`
  → `2666.67`

`INDEX(6:6,N(IF(1,expression)))` is a required hack<sup>*</sup> in order to force Excel to return an array for `expression` since the second argument of `INDEX()` is evaluated to a single value by default. Using just `INDEX(6:6,expression)` in `AK6` would lead to

`INDEX((6:6),COLUMN()-(COLUMN($AE:$AE)-COLUMN($F:$F))-COLUMN(INDEX(6:6,1):INDEX(6:6,$I$2))-$I$1+(COLUMN()-(COLUMN($AE:$AE)-COLUMN($F:$F))-COLUMN(INDEX(6:6,1):INDEX(6:6,$I$2))-$I$1>=COLUMN($R:$R)))`

→ `INDEX(6:6,37-(31-6)-COLUMN($A$6:$L$6)-1+(37-(31-6)-COLUMN($A$6:$L$6)-1>=18))`

→ `INDEX(6:6,12-1-1+(12-1-1>=18))`
→ `INDEX(6:6,10)`
→ `24000`

since inside an expression returning a single value, `COLUMN(multi-cell-range)` returns the column of the first cell of the range.

The `+(COLUMN()-(COLUMN($AE:$AE)-COLUMN($F:$F))-COLUMN(INDEX(6:6,1):INDEX(6:6,$I$2))-$I$1>=COLUMN($R:$R))` adjusts for the gap between the order tables for 2018 and 2019 (column `R`). Note that the `N(IF(` hack is not required in this case as the previously used hack has already forced an array evaluation of the second argument of `INDEX` and thus the `COLUMN()` function evaluate to arrays.

The `IFERROR()` function is required in case the formula exists in a cell close to the left side of the sheet, resulting in either accessing text, or attempting to access a cell to the left of column `A`.

**Notes:**

- The prettified formula actually works if entered.
- The brackets around `(6:6)` in the prettified version are required to force the `6:6` to remain on its own line.

**Caveats:**

- **There can be no numbers in the cells of the n columns to the left of the orders** (where n is specified by the value in `I2`). If there are any numbers there, the formula, as is, will include them in the revenue calculation.
- **There can be no gap between the Dec 2018 Revenue and the Jan 2019 Revenue columns.** The formula can be modified to allow for such a gap if one is desired.
- The gap between the two orders tables (`R:R`) must remain exactly one column wide. Otherwise, the formula, as is, will break.
- The inter- orders tables gap cannot contain any numbers. Otherwise, they will be treated as additional orders.

---

<sub><sup>*</sup> The explanation of exactly why the hack works will have to wait until I figure it out for myself first ;-)</sub>